# Controling Web browser through VB.net application

Tags: vb.net, process

I want to open separate instances of internet explorer to specified websites.  After they are open I would like to cycle through them being displayed on a timer.

I have the following code, but I am not able to switch to the specified IE process:

```
Dim rotatethrough As Boolean = True
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 'I have a list box that contains the website URLs
        Dim Processname As New List(Of String)
        Dim processnum(Environment.ProcessorCount) As Process
        processnum(i) = New Process
        processnum(i) = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ListBox1.Items(i)) 'start up seperate instances of IE for each website
    Next
    Do While rotatethrough = True
        For n = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            AppActivate(processnum(n).Id) 'activate the websites
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Next
    Loop
```

So far the code opens up the separate instance of IE but fails on appactivate because " Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".  I have tried creating IE as an object, but then I am not sure how to get the correct process ID for the corresponding listbox item.

ANY help would be awesome, I just can seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are a few issues to correct in your code. **First of all,** `Environment.ProcessorCount` returns the number of _**processORS**_ on your machine. This is different from the number of _**processES**_ that are currently running. I think what you are after is rather `ListBox1.Items.Count - 1`.

Comment: **Secondly,** you are creating a new array by the name `processnum` every time the loop runs, but you appear to have already defined another one by the same name elsewhere (the former is likely the cause of the exception you mentioned). If you want to change the array's size you can do so _before_ the loop using the [**`ReDim` statement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement).